# Hosting & Securing Email Server

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix

I recently decided that I was going to host my own email server and ditch iCloud and hotmail. I have went through the same set up over and over on howtoforge about setting up an email server. I can never get traffic to pass even though I use ports 993, 465 and 587 instead of 25 and 143. I recently created a droplet in DigitalOcean with the same setup and wah-lah, mail is working no problem. So that tells me Comcast is blocking something. Is there a way I can run an email server at home so I don't have to pay $20/month to run a server in the public cloud when I can run it in my own private cloud?

Comment: We use postmaster from within a google cloud instance. 25000 mails each month for a few dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for production (that is, something you remotely care about)? If so:

You don't want to run an email server at home.

No really, you don't want to run an email server at home.

Between the ISP port blocking, dynamic addresses, potential downtime where mail can just get lost or bounce, among many other things...

Learning is awesome. If you're doing it as a personal project for learning on a spare domain, that's super neat, and I encourage you to go on. But if you're doing it for your own personal inbox, I highly reccomend against it.

And to answer your actual question, it's entirely likely Comcast is blocking some inbound ports for residential circuts. You could test this by forwarding ports you want to test to a daemon you know is listening, and then attempt to access it from a VPS.

For example, to test port 25, configure your router to forward port 25 to port 80 on a known webserver on your LAN. From there, just run `curl [your ip]:25` and see what happens. If it works, Comcast likely isn't blocking. If it doesn't, try again at a high port like 8046. If it works there, but not at your desired port, you're likely being blocked, at which point your only options are:

1) Host externally

2) Use some sort of VPN to gain entry to your network and then access services over the VPN

3) switch ports to an unblocked one

4) contact comcast (not likely to go anywhere).

Comment: @Jay, any chance you could select an answer if one helped you, or request clarification if one didn't?

Answer (score 0):

It is common for ISPs to block outgoing traffic on port 25 from dynamic IP addresses.  This is desired by the email server administration community as dynamic addresses are the source of a lot of SPAM.  Even if your ISP does not block traffic, there are blacklists and other mechanisms that are used to prevent dynamic addresses from sending email.

Check [Frequent question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/email?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) for some idea where to start.

Many years ago I started [using a dynamic IP address](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/mx-on-a-dynamic-ip-address/).  With a well configured server that worked reasonably well, but eventually I was forced to use a static IP address.  Times have changed.

Large ISPs often make it difficult to get a static IP address at a reasonable cost.  (They usually require a business service.)  A smaller local ISP may provide a static IP for free or at least for a reasonable cost.  The static IP should come with unblocked connectivity to the Internet.  In some cases you may have to ask to have the blocking removed.  In any case you should be asking to have your PTR record configured to use your mail server's DNS name.